# Which is faster ? double [][] matrix or ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>

Tags: java, performance, arraylist, big-o

In Java which is faster note that I don't need the flexibility of (remove, add)in Big O thing. But I certainly need the Access Big O.

The operation is only to multiply 2 matrices or subtract, add etc..

Also note that the array is primitive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`double[][]` is much more memory efficient than using ArrayLists and Double. It will use a fraction of the memory meaning you will get better caching behaviour.  Also the `double` in `double[]` will be continuous in memory, also improving cache performance.

BTW: `Double` may be rather randomly arranged in memory and there for the cache.

Comment: (+1) for considering locality of reference.

Answer (score 6):

`double[][]` will be faster because it'll avoid autoboxing during arithmetic operations.

Answer (score 6):

With `double [][]` you won't need to worry about Autoboxing or internal resizing/copying operations, therefore it will be faster.

On the other hand, the performance difference should be unnoticeable unless you're working with extremely large collections.

Comment: Please define extremely large ?

Answer (score 1):

double [] [] is faster. In java there is no statement more primitive than that.

Answer (score 1):

The operations on `double[][]` and `ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>` will *run in the same [Big-O bounds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)*.

That is, the *asymptomatic bounds are the same* -- if an ArrayList does not have to *resize* then access is truly `O(1)` for index operations (even though if the `C` [constant] might be larger for the access *and* the double/Double boxing *and* memory-locality). Choosing one over the other *will not increase or reduce the complexity* or change the Big-O.

Which one is wall-clock faster? My bets are on the array, but the only way "to know for certain" -- including "how much faster", and in which cases -- is to *benchmark the different structures on the given environment/problem/problem size and compare the results*. (This should be one of the first steps when trying to "optimize".)

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

The array should be faster as the ArrayLust uses also an internal array and therefor you have an additional call (get(x).get(y)) which will consume further time.

Answer (score 0):

The `[][]` array would be faster. `ArrayList` access is essentially just as fast (it uses `[]` internally) but the extra work object-based work needed (it has to look into two objects instead of one array, for example) would make it slightly slower.